# RPI 3 as a wifi access point, performance question

Tags: wifi

I use the rpi 2 (+ a wifi dongle with a RTL8188CUS chipset) as a wifi access point with a nodejs server on it.

I'm considering switching to the rpi 3, for cost reasons, but I'm worried about loss of performance (as in not being able to connect as many devices).

I read people have been complaining about the [poor performance of the rpi3 wifi chipset](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=138312)

I was wondering if anyone had run performance tests with the rpi3 set up as an AP. How many simultaneous connections it can handle ?

Comment: I don't own a 3 but the pi in general has limited potential for this (as you seem to have experienced) due to low network throughput -- it is probably less than most of the devices that connect to it, so sort of like hooking a bunch of big pipes up to one smalll one and expecting the water to flow nicely.  Separating the wifi chip from the USB solves this to a degree but you are probably correct in observing is it a budget item.

Comment: @goldilocks what do you mean by "the pi has limited potential due to low network throughput" ?

Comment: (I moved all that to a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40611/discussion-between-goldilocks-and-clementine) so it does not detract from your question -- good luck!).

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any performance issues with the Wifi on the Raspberry Pi 3.  To be honest, with the WiFi being on its own chip it no longer shares the USB buss, as such I would expect the same or better performance.